# Laplace transform of a product of charateristic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform

I hope you are doing great!

I wanted to work on my game of complex analysis with a simple problem: the Laplace transform of a product of characteristic functions $\mathbb{1}_{[0,b]}$ and $\mathbb{1}_{[a,c]}$ with $a < b < c$. You can for instance think of those functions (distributions) as representing two overlapping rectangular waves (or pulses) traveling on a rope.

We know that the product of such functions should be just $\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}$. Therefore the Laplace transform of their product is just, with $s \in \mathbb{C}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{\mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(t)\} & = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{1}_{[a,b]}(t) e^{-st} \, dt \\
&= \frac{e^{-as}-e^{-bs}}{s}
\end{align}
$$

From the integrand above, I deduced that the region of convergence (ROC) was $\mathbb{C}$.

So far, so good. Now, I wanted to derive this result, the hard way, using the property of Laplace transform applied to products of functions:

$$
\mathcal{L}\{f(t)g(t)\} = \frac{1}{2i\pi} \int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} F(s) G(r-s) \, ds
$$

with $r \in \mathbb{C}$, $F = \mathcal{L}\{f\}$ and $G = \mathcal{L}\{g\}$.

So, here, we would have:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{L}\{\mathbb{1}_{[0,b]}(t) \, \mathbb{1}_{[a,c]}(t)\} &= \frac{1}{2i\pi}  \int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \left( \frac{1-e^{-bs}}{s} \right)\left( \frac{e^{-a(r-s)}-e^{-c(r-s)}}{(r-s)} \right) ds \\
&= \frac{1}{2i\pi}  \int_{\gamma-i\infty}^{\gamma+i\infty} \frac{1}{s(r-s)} \left( e^{-a(r-s)}-e^{-c(r-s)} - e^{-ar+(a-b)s} + e^{-cr+(c-b)s} \right) ds
\end{align}
$$

I see that the integrand is bounded but I got stuck at computing this integral. I see that there are different potential approaches (Expansion in Entire Series or using some properties of [Exponential Integral Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)). Would you have some derivation to propose?

> I would greatly appreciate explicit bounds on the integrand when a claim on an integral going to 0 on a part of contour is made (as in Jordan's lemma).